# Перебор и сравнение значений из словаря

Tags: python, словари

У меня есть следующий словарь:

```
{'people' = [{'Name' : 'Andrei', 'age' : '19'},{'Name' : 'Vladimir' , 'age' : '19'},{'Name' :' Anna', 'age' : '21'}]}
```

А также есть папка, путь к которой 'path//', и в которой лежат документы, названия которых совпадают с именами в словаре:

```
Andrei.txt
Vladimir.txt
Anna.txt
```

Мне необходимо циклом перебрать все значения "name" и проверить, присутствует ли файл с этим именем в папке. Если присутствует - print('True').

Когда я пытался перебирать стандартным циклом значения ключа 'name' мне выдавало ошибку:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Неизвестно, что у вас за "стандартный" способ, но  попробуйте перебрать"нестандартным".

Comment: И такой словарь наверняка выдаст ошибку уже при создании, потому что переменные Andrei, Anna итд не определены.

Comment: @Эникейщик Так и есть, уже проверил, ошибка.

Comment: Поставьте их в кавычки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, некорректно написал свой словарь, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение Вашей задачи:

```py
import os.path

people = {'Name' : 'Andrei', 'age' : 19},{'Name' : 'Vladimir' , 'age' : 19},{'Name' : 'Anna', 'age' : 21}

for d in people:
    if os.path.exists('path/{}.txt'.format(d['Name'])):
        print(d['Name'], '.txt: ', 'True', sep='')
```

Не знаю, что в Вашем понятии "стандартный цикл", но значения словаря перебираются с помощью такого цикла:

```py
for key in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[key])
```

представленный код напечатает все значения словаря `dictionary`.

Однако следует заметить, что в представленном Вами коде объявлен не словарь, а кортеж словарей (попробуйте `print(type(people))`). Таким образом, необходимо сначала перебирать словари в кортеже, а потом уже из каждого словаря получать значение по заданному ключу (в Вашем случае `'Name'`), что я и сделал в представленном коде.

Для исправленного варианта вопроса код будет выглядеть так:

```py
import os.path

your_dict = {'people': [{'Name' : 'Andrei', 'age' : '19'},{'Name' : 'Vladimir' , 'age' : '19'},{'Name' :' Anna', 'age' : '21'}]}

for d in your_dict['people']:
    if os.path.exists('path/{}.txt'.format(d['Name'])):
        print(d['Name'], '.txt: ', 'True', sep='')
```

Теперь у нас есть словарь, в котором ключ – строка, а значение – список словарей. Список перебирается так же, как кортеж в первом варианте.

Comment: Прошу прощения, изначально некорректно написал словарь. Данный код применим к обновленному словарю?

Comment: Выдает ошибку 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Comment: @6crimes Где именно? Представленный выше код? У меня прекрасно отрабатывает на VS 2017.

Comment: @6crimes Если Вы про второй блок кода, это просто для примера.

Comment: Я про первый блок кода. Посмотрите пожалуйста, я отредактировал в вопросе свой словарь. Может быть из-за этого данный скрипт у меня выдает ошибку.

Comment: @6crimes Конечно из-за этого. Как я указал в ответе, если Вы внимательно читали, у Вас был кортеж словарей, а не словарь. Теперь же Вы сделали словарь, где ключ – строка, а значение – список словарей. Мне редактировать ответ для Ваших исправлений?

Comment: Я был бы очень рад, если вы отредактируете!

Comment: @6crimes Хорошо, но на будущее: проверяйте синтаксис тех примеров кода что вы пишете, а лучше попытайтесь их запустить, прежде чем вставлять в вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, прошу прощения,. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @6crimes Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как решение, если он был полезен.